# C What is ""first[a[c]-'a']++;"

Tags: c

I have started with C in my school and (as I'm slowly ending) I came across a question about programming an anagram checker. After some thinking I still couldn't figure out anything but a seperate counter for each specific letter and if the counters would match, it would be an anagram. But that seems terribly long to write (especially on paper).
So I went to search for an answer of some sorts through google, looking for an anagram solver and managed to come across some code but there's one thing there which I don't understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_anagram(char [], char []);

int main() {
   char a[100], b[100];
   int flag;

   printf("Enter first string\n");
   gets(a);

   printf("Enter second string\n");
   gets(b);

   flag = check_anagram(a, b);

   if (flag == 1)
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", a, b);
   else
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", a, b);

   return 0;
}

int check_anagram(char a[], char b[]) {
    int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c = 0;

    while (a[c] != '\0') {
        first[a[c] - 'a']++;
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;

    while (b[c] != '\0') {
        second[b[c] - 'a']++;
        c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++) {
        if (first[c] != second[c])
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

At first I thought this wouldn't work for anagrams longer than 26 letters so I tried some random strings longer than 26 and it did actually work. However when I went through the code, I saw that I can't understand what:
`first[a[c]-'a']++;` and `second[b[c]-'a']++;`
mean. Could someone please clarify what this is, what it does or at least what should I look for to realize these things because it doesn't add up well in my head.

**EDIT 1**
- First of all you people are fast...
- Second of all, if I understand this correctly, this program shouldn't cope well with capital letters or different caps (e.g.: HELLO and hello)?

Comment: Do not use `gets()`, it was even deprecated in modern [tag:c] standards.

Comment: Yes, the program will treat capital letters as different from lowercase letters.  The usual way around that would be to convert both inputs to all one case, such as via the `tolower()` function.  Moreover, the program would probably try to access array `a` out of its bounds if it encountered an uppercase letter (depends on character encoding), which would produce undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  Worse than that: not only does the program invoke undefined behavior for uppercase letters, or any characters that is not a lowercase letter, it will invoke undefined behavior even for lowercase characters if the systems character set is not ASCII.  The array sizes are 26 exactly, so the program assumes no letters outside `'a'`-`'z'` are present in the strings and lowercase letters `'a'` through `'z'` are contiguous, which is not true for EBCDIC...

Comment: @chqrlie: Forgot about EBCDIC, I think the easiest fix for a simple program as this would then be to use `first[256]` and not use that `-'a'` bit at all. (added that to the bottom of my answer). Although I strongly dislike EBCDIC, not in the least because of the nightmares it gave me when I had to work with COBOL... truly horrible

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: A simple method is indeed to use an array of size 256, and use `first[a[c] & 255]++;` because of other nightmarish constraints such as: `char` may have more than 8 bits, and may be signed too `:(`

Answer (score 8):

It's a common trick, really: `a` is an array of characters, each character is an ASCII value (ie numeric, int compatible), so you can use it in mathematical expressions. `c` is an int, and is used to traverse the character array `a`. Assuming all characters in `a` will be lower-case letters, then the expression

```
a[c] - 'a'
```

Will evaluate to `0` for `a`, `1` for `b` and so on. because `first` is an array of ints, 26 long (`int first[26]`), each lower-case letter will have a valid, corresponding index ('a' - 'a' = 0, 'z' - 'a' = 25), so you're basically counting the occurrences for each character. `second[b[c] - 'a']++` does the exact same thing for the second string: counting the occurrences of each letter in the string.
At the end, you're iterating over these letter-count arrays, comparing the values for each letter (occ. count). If all of the letters occur an equal amount of times in both strings, you're dealing with an anagram. If not, you're returning `0`.

This trick is more commonly used to convert digits into ints:

```
char foo[] = "123";
int result = 0;
for (int i=0;foo[i] != 0;++i)
    result = result * 10 + (foo[i] - '0');
printf("String: %s vs int: %d\n", foo, result);
```

## [demo](https://eval.in/497807)

#### For completeness' sake all ASCII characters and their corresponding decimal (ie int) values:

```
Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char Dec  Oct   Hex
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(nul)   0 0000 0x00 | (sp)   32 0040 0x20 | @      64 0100 0x40 | `      96 0140 0x60
(soh)   1 0001 0x01 | !      33 0041 0x21 | A      65 0101 0x41 | a      97 0141 0x61
(stx)   2 0002 0x02 | "      34 0042 0x22 | B      66 0102 0x42 | b      98 0142 0x62
(etx)   3 0003 0x03 | #      35 0043 0x23 | C      67 0103 0x43 | c      99 0143 0x63
(eot)   4 0004 0x04 | $      36 0044 0x24 | D      68 0104 0x44 | d     100 0144 0x64
(enq)   5 0005 0x05 | %      37 0045 0x25 | E      69 0105 0x45 | e     101 0145 0x65
(ack)   6 0006 0x06 | &      38 0046 0x26 | F      70 0106 0x46 | f     102 0146 0x66
(bel)   7 0007 0x07 | '      39 0047 0x27 | G      71 0107 0x47 | g     103 0147 0x67
(bs)    8 0010 0x08 | (      40 0050 0x28 | H      72 0110 0x48 | h     104 0150 0x68
(ht)    9 0011 0x09 | )      41 0051 0x29 | I      73 0111 0x49 | i     105 0151 0x69
(nl)   10 0012 0x0a | *      42 0052 0x2a | J      74 0112 0x4a | j     106 0152 0x6a
(vt)   11 0013 0x0b | +      43 0053 0x2b | K      75 0113 0x4b | k     107 0153 0x6b
(np)   12 0014 0x0c | ,      44 0054 0x2c | L      76 0114 0x4c | l     108 0154 0x6c
(cr)   13 0015 0x0d | -      45 0055 0x2d | M      77 0115 0x4d | m     109 0155 0x6d
(so)   14 0016 0x0e | .      46 0056 0x2e | N      78 0116 0x4e | n     110 0156 0x6e
(si)   15 0017 0x0f | /      47 0057 0x2f | O      79 0117 0x4f | o     111 0157 0x6f
(dle)  16 0020 0x10 | 0      48 0060 0x30 | P      80 0120 0x50 | p     112 0160 0x70
(dc1)  17 0021 0x11 | 1      49 0061 0x31 | Q      81 0121 0x51 | q     113 0161 0x71
(dc2)  18 0022 0x12 | 2      50 0062 0x32 | R      82 0122 0x52 | r     114 0162 0x72
(dc3)  19 0023 0x13 | 3      51 0063 0x33 | S      83 0123 0x53 | s     115 0163 0x73
(dc4)  20 0024 0x14 | 4      52 0064 0x34 | T      84 0124 0x54 | t     116 0164 0x74
(nak)  21 0025 0x15 | 5      53 0065 0x35 | U      85 0125 0x55 | u     117 0165 0x75
(syn)  22 0026 0x16 | 6      54 0066 0x36 | V      86 0126 0x56 | v     118 0166 0x76
(etb)  23 0027 0x17 | 7      55 0067 0x37 | W      87 0127 0x57 | w     119 0167 0x77
(can)  24 0030 0x18 | 8      56 0070 0x38 | X      88 0130 0x58 | x     120 0170 0x78
(em)   25 0031 0x19 | 9      57 0071 0x39 | Y      89 0131 0x59 | y     121 0171 0x79
(sub)  26 0032 0x1a | :      58 0072 0x3a | Z      90 0132 0x5a | z     122 0172 0x7a
(esc)  27 0033 0x1b | ;      59 0073 0x3b | [      91 0133 0x5b | {     123 0173 0x7b
(fs)   28 0034 0x1c |       62 0076 0x3e | ^      94 0136 0x5e | ~     126 0176 0x7e
(us)   31 0037 0x1f | ?      63 0077 0x3f | _      95 0137 0x5f | (del) 127 0177 0x7f
```

In short, then: read `first[a[c] -'a']++;` as though it says:

```
first[a[c] - 97]++;//a[c] will be value between 97 and 122 so first[0..25]++
```

---

## Update

Seeing as you're not 100% on what the possible problems might be when dealing with upper-case strings, here's a breakdown of what would happen if you pass a strings like *"FOO"* and *"OOF"* to your function:

```
int first[26] = {0};// valid indexes are 0 to 25
//if a[c] == 'F', this evaluates to first[65-97] or first[-32]
first[a[c] - 'a']++;//DANGER: Out of bounds!
```

The reason why you may not notice the problem straight away is simply because you're passing an array of chars (a string) to your function. An array decays into a pointer once passed to a function. Arguably, and array almost always decays into a pointer:

> The deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

This means that writing `a[c]` is the same as writing `*(a+c)`, and writing `first[a[c] - 'a']` is equivalent to: `*(first + (a[c] - 'a'));`, which in this case could evaluate to `first[-32]`, which of course is the same as `*(first - 32);`.
That's asking your machine to take the address of `first[0]`, and move 32 steps backwards (each step being `sizeof(int)`). You have no way of knowing what is in that memory you're accessing: trap values, other variables... anything could happen. The behaviour of such expressions is *undefined*.

To get around this issue, you can either check to make sure the characters are in the `a-z` range like so:

```
if (a[c] > 96 && a[c] <= 'z')//96 == 'a' -1
   first[a[c] -'a']++;
else
    return -1;//indicate error
```

or simply convert to lower case:

first[tolower(a[c]) - 'a']++;

Calling `tolower` naively assumes that the characters in `a` will be either upper- or lower-case letters. This doesn't have to be the case, so if I were you, I'd do both: convert to lower, then check if the resulting char is indeed a letter (in theory, your function could receive strings like *"foo: 123!"*, containing spaces, digits, and other characters).

## Simplest fix addressing out-of-bounds access + ASCII vs EBCDIC

All in all, you could simply increase the size of `first` and `second` to `256`, and just write this:

```
first[a[c]]++;
//and
second[b[c]]++;
```

That solves the upper-lower case problem, and solves the problems EBCDIC vs ASCII, too. When checking for anagrams, you can safely skip over the first elements (`first[0]` now only counts the terminating nul-character, which is of no use anyway).

Answer (score 2):

This is a short expression for counting lowercase letters.

Let's look at parts of this expression:

- `a[c]` means "character of `a` at position `c`
- `a[c]-'a'` means "zero-based index of lowercase letter of `a` at position `c`"
- `first[a[c]-'a']++` means "increment an element of array `first` at index of lowercase letter of `a` at position `c`"

Answer (score 0):

It is using a one liner to count the number of occurrences of a letter in a word. Lets look at this broken down:

```
first[a[c]-'a']++;
```

1. `a[c] - 'a'` is getting the number representation of the alphabet character, so imagine if `a[c]` was 'b', we would get the number 1.
2. `first[a[c] - 'a']` Is accessing the array `first` at the position of the letter.
3. `first[a[c] - 'a']++` is increment the number at that position.

So if you encounter a 'b', your list will look like this:

```
{0, 1, 0, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `first[a[c]-'a']++;` let us divide it into parts :

```
a[c] // value of a[] at index c so returns a character at index c
// as we know 'a' is starting point of alphabets but in case of ascii values
// it is not (it is 97)
// Here we are using int value of a[c] for indexing of first[] and it
// it should not start with 97 so we need to subtract 95 thats why
a[c] - 'a' // returns 0 in case of first char as 'a'
// NOW array first[0] will be treated as counter of 'a'
// likewise first[1] will be counter of 'b'
```